# on latest android the app icon starts new activity

Tags: android

After testing my application on multiple device i found out that on some of them if i click application icon it shows me 
 `WelcomeActivity` instead of bringing back the application from background. I know that WelcomeActivity is LAUNCHER but on my other devices the app icon alway bring me back the background application.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

After WelcomeActivity i use MainActivity. and usually the app is putted to the background while that was alive.

Comment: So whats your question / problem?

Comment: I suspect it's to do with memory management - The Android System is obviously destroying the Activity/App (probably to free resources) on some devices - The System decides who lives and who dies!.

Comment: Two options seems probable to me : The devices are running low on memory, so they kill the app when it's backgrounded, and it's restarting. 
Second option : check in the Developer options of the devices, and make sure that "Don't keep activities" is unchecked. Otherwise, as soon as an activity isn't on the foreground, it's killed immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Because

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)